# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: Check previous build status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

What is the best way to check whether if previous stage failed or not using Jenkins **declarative** **pipeline** and if it is failed  then run rollback command.

I just tried as below but it throws an error as below.

> > Scripts not permitted to use method
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
> >     getRawBuild. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject
> >     this signature.

```
    stage('Deploy to production'){
        when{
            beforeAgent true
            expression{return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master"}
        }
        steps{
            script{
                    echo "Deploying production environment"
                    sh "helm install ...."

                }else {
                    error "Buid was not confirmed"
                }
    stage('Roll Back'){
        when{
            expression {
                !hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS.equals(currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()) == true
            }
        }
        steps{
            script{
                sh "helm rollback <release> 0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `!("SUCCESS".equals(currentBuild.previousBuild.result))`.

It seems that `rawBuild` is restricted to trusted libraries (Globally defined libraries), or you'll need to add an exception to that method.

But using `.previousBuild` directly should work.

https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals

Comment: thanks for your response..Can i use this in when condition?